# How do i dispatch redux outside provider?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I am trying to save a notification from firebase to redux when the application is on quit.

But I need to do that in app.js, how can I dispatch redux action when I am not even on the component?

Here is what I am trying to do

```js
componentDidMount(){
  messaging().getInitialNotification().then(remoteMessage) => { 
    dispatch(action({
      notification:true,
      data:remoteMessage.data
    }));
  }
}
  
render(){
  return(
    <Provider context={MyContext} store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: `store.dispatch(whatever)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first export your store like

```
export const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    auth: authReducer,
    team: teamReducer,
  }),
  applyMiddleware(thunk),
);

<Provider context={MyContext} store={store}>
  <App />
</Provider>
```

make sure this is the same store you are passing to the provider

Then you can import this store wherever you want and use it like

```
import {store} from './index';
import * as actions from './actions';

store.dispatch(actions.getMySolution());
```

Happy learning!

Edit:
As @markerikson said in the comments below, it is not advised to do so until it is really necessary.

So, I will mention one practical use case.
let say you want to dispatch an action inside your API call to set loader and unset loader once the API call is completed.

```
import {store} from './index';
import * as actions from './actions';
import axios from 'axios';

export const get = (params) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    store.dispatch(actions.setLoading());
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((data) => {
        store.dispatch(actions.stopLoading());
        resolve(data.data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        store.dispatch(actions.stopLoading());
        reject(e);
      });
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you sir :D

Comment: Note that we specifically advise _against_ trying to import the store into other files in the codebase unless _absolutely_ necessary: https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#only-one-redux-store-per-app . In this particular example, `<App>` is already inside the `<Provider>`, so you should be able to wrap the class component in `connect()` and dispatch actions from within the component as normal via the `mapDispatch` argument.

Comment: Thanks, @markerikson I should have mentioned that too. I will add it now.